# Central limit theorem - speed of convergence in center vs tails

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

I've been told that one of the implications of the central limit theorem is that as we increase the sampling of random variables, we converge faster to a normal distribution in the center and slower out in the tails.

But this isn't immediately obvious to me. A Google search on this hardly yields any result, but I did find work on the Chernoff bound and Berry-Essen theorem that give estimates on the speed of convergence. Can someone give a clearer explanation or point me to more references on this?

Thanks!

Comment: *one of the implications of the central limit theorem is that as we increase the sampling of random variables, we converge faster to a normal distribution in the center and slower out in the tails*... What is your source?

Comment: @Did: Thanks. My professor mentioned it in a lecture, but see for instance page 2 on http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/CLT.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the source. Page 2 reads "The exact form of convergence is not just a technical nicety — the normalized sums do not converge uniformly to a normal distribution. This means that the tails of the distribution converge more slowly than its center." This seems to say that, when $n$ is large, the function $G_n:x\mapsto |F_n(x)-\Phi(x)|$ is minimum at $0$ (or around $0$). This assertion is quite intriguing since $G_n\geqslant0$ and its limits at $\pm\infty$ are both $0$ (note that the rest of the text does not come back to this). I guess there is a typo.

Comment: Faster relative to what?  Because the expected value is correct, the total error in the center and tails has to balance. But relative to the normal approximation, a small error in the tails can still be large.  Consider the Bernstein inequalities.  The tails converge exponentially in `n`.  The normal distribution falls off as `e^(-x^2)`. It is easy for objectively small errors to be large relative to that tail!